# Setting custom privacy for test uses for album

Tags: facebook, privacy

I have searched the forum but cannot find an existing question that covers this...

I have a Facebook app and have created 4 test users
I have made friend connections among those test users
Before I programmatically do the following steps, I am attempting them using the FB web pages...
Logging in as one test user, I create an album
I want to set the privacy of this album:

- Custom Privacy
- Specific people or lists
- And then enter the test user name of one of the friends of that test user

Problem: FB does not seem to recognize my test user friends within this dialog/text box
Even if I type in the full name of the friend and save, the privacy is not persisted correctly

Has anyone tried to do this?
Thanks.